# morphism from coproduct into product in abelian categories

Tags: abelian-categories

Let consider an abelian category with a projective generator $ R $. The canonical morphism $\coprod R\to\prod R $ (taken over the same indexing set $ I $) is monic?

The answer is affirmative if $ I $ is finite (also without requiring to $R$ to be a projective generator), but what about in the infinite case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. For assume on contrary that the answer was yes. Let $K$ be a field, then $K$ is both a projective generator and a injective cogenerator in the category $\mathscr V_K$ of the $K$-vectorspace. Thus our statement also holds in $\mathscr V_K^{\text{op}}$, consequently the morphism $\coprod K\to\prod K$ is both monic and epic, hence an isomophism, which is false if the indexing set is infinite.